# Small crypto library in C

Tags: c, cryptography

What is the best C crypto library for small devices? My device is very limited in memory (only about 50 KB left). Also I do not need all of the fancy cryptography algorithms. An encryption, MAC algorithm and a CSPRNG is enough.

I've tried the following but they are simply too big:

- OpenSSL
- Cryptlib
- NaCl
- Nettle
- WolfSSL
- mbedTLS

Comment: If you link statically, you shouldn't care about the library size, no?

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/awslabs/s2n

This is amazons attempt to rebuild openssl with only the modern features needed.  It has according to amazon passed 3 security audits.

It has something like 6,000 lines of code.